# converting tuples into strings

Tags: arrays, string, tuples, maze

So my problem is i have a tuple with tuples inside it and i want to replace the 1 inside the tuples into # and 0 to .

Although im still to figure that one my myself when i convert the main tuple to a string i dont want the parentises and i want it displayed in columns but its not working so if someone could help me i would appreciate it a lot.

```
maze = ((1,1,1,1),(1,0,0,1),(1,0,0,1),(1,0,0,1),(1,1,1,1))

def tuplestr(maze):

    string = ""
    string += str(maze)
     return string
```

so basically in the the result is ((1,1,1,1),(1,0,0,1),(1,0,0,1),(1,0,0,1),(1,1,1,1)) but in a string and i want this as a result

```
1 1 1 1
1 0 0 1
1 0 0 1
1 0 0 1
1 1 1 1
```

instead of this ((1,1,1,1),(1,0,0,1),(1,0,0,1),(1,0,0,1),(1,1,1,1)) string

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you want--is it `for row in maze:
    print(" ".join(map(str, row)))` or `for row in maze:
    print(" ".join("#" if x else "." for x in row))`? The expected output is 1s and 0s but the description indicates `#` and `.`. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Well in reality i want to print te string like that and the 1 to be # and 0 to be "." but i didnt put that on the result just for the problem not become confusing

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Does the above code solve the problem?

Comment: It kind of work but how can i save "for row in maze: print(" ".join("#" if x else "." for x in row))" in a variable?

Comment: Is `result = "\n".join(" ".join("#" if x else "." for x in row) for row in maze)` what you're looking for?

Comment: what i want is for example for that maze is the function to return it like this ````#######\n#.....#\n#.....#\n#.....#\n####### ```` if its not printed, and if it is printed i want it in an array

Comment: Hmm. The above code gives you that string exactly, but your question doesn't say anything about an array. What is that supposed to look like? You can edit your question to show what you need.

Comment: ok so ill clarify so basically i want the function to return the string that is the result of this `````print(" ".join("#" if x else "." for x in row))````` but if its not printed i just want the string but without the "\n"

Comment: The `result =` code above does exactly that (assuming you add a `for row in maze:` before your above code. I'm confused...

Comment: but for example when i put that the function doesnt end

Comment: Are you trying to `return` it instead of `result =`? By "doesn't end", do you mean an infinite loop? How large is your maze?

Comment: Thanks for the help but i already fixed the problem. Thanks mate

Comment: Great. You should post an answer to your own question (this is encouraged!), then mark it as accepted. This will help future visitors with the same problem as you.